# how to send/receive data Byte by Byte

Tags: php, python, client-server

I'm triggering a php script on my webserver from a python script on my client. I'm processing binary data that I make available to my client script to be parsed like:

```
$file = "gw/gateway.py"
if (file_exists($file)) {
    $gw_file_sz = filesize($file);
    $filesz1 = $gw_file_sz/256;
    $filesz2 = $gw_file_sz%256;
}
    $binarydata = pack("C*", 0x01, $year1, $year2, $day1, $day2, $min1, $min2, $sec, 0x00, 0x3f, 0x02, 0x00, 0x1c, 0x2c , 0x4c, 0xdf, 0xcb,
                                                                                             0x02, 0x00, 0x1c, 0x2c , 0x5c, 0xe8, 0x41,
                                                 0x04, 0x00, 0x1c, 0x2c , 0x5c, 0xe4, 0x38,
                                                 0x02, 0x00, 0x1c, 0x2c , 0x5c, 0xe3, 0x7b,
                                                 0x02, 0x00, 0x1c, 0x2c , 0x4c, 0xdf, 0xbf,
                                                 0x02, 0x00, 0x1c, 0x2c , 0x5c, 0xe7, 0xd7,
                                                 0x02, 0x00, 0x1c, 0x2c , 0x4c, 0xdf, 0x64,
                                                 0x02, 0x00, 0x1c, 0x2c , 0x5c, 0xe7, 0x7a,
                                                 0x02, 0x00, 0x1c, 0x2c , 0x5c, 0xe8, 0x22,
                                               0x08, $filesz1, $filesz2);

echo $binarydata;
```

Now this works fine with these data but how do I append my file $file at the end of this stream to be picked up by my client?
On the Python side, I read all the data from a *fh = StringIO(data)* where I get Bytes like *MyByte = ord(fh.read(1))*

[EDIT]
I just tried to append the data at the end (before the echo) like:

```
    $fh = fopen($file);
    for ($i=0;$i<filesize($file); $i++) {
        $binarydata.=pack("C*",fread($fh,1));
    }
    fclose($fh);
```

But it doesn't seem to work, why not...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are outputting a data stream, I don't see any reason why you can't just echo the entire file contents directly. I also modified $filesz1 to what I think you may have intended.

```
$file = "gw/gateway.py"
if (file_exists($file)) {
    $gw_file_sz = filesize($file);
    $filesz1 = floor($gw_file_sz/256);
    $filesz2 = $gw_file_sz%256;
}
$binarydata = pack("C*", 0x01, $year1, $year2, $day1, $day2, $min1, $min2, $sec, 
    0x00, 0x3f, 0x02, 0x00, 0x1c, 0x2c , 0x4c, 0xdf, 0xcb,
    0x02, 0x00, 0x1c, 0x2c , 0x5c, 0xe8, 0x41,
    0x04, 0x00, 0x1c, 0x2c , 0x5c, 0xe4, 0x38,
    0x02, 0x00, 0x1c, 0x2c , 0x5c, 0xe3, 0x7b,
    0x02, 0x00, 0x1c, 0x2c , 0x4c, 0xdf, 0xbf,
    0x02, 0x00, 0x1c, 0x2c , 0x5c, 0xe7, 0xd7,
    0x02, 0x00, 0x1c, 0x2c , 0x4c, 0xdf, 0x64,
    0x02, 0x00, 0x1c, 0x2c , 0x5c, 0xe7, 0x7a,
    0x02, 0x00, 0x1c, 0x2c , 0x5c, 0xe8, 0x22,
    0x08, $filesz1, $filesz2);

echo $binarydata;
echo file_get_contents($file);
```

Comment: hi JMack, Thanks for your response, will this way everything be in the same stream, won't it open a new one for file_get_contents()?

Comment: No, it shouldn't open a new stream. It should all be one stream. This would be the same as doing `echo $binarydata.file_get_contents($file);` which creates a single string from all the data before echoing it.